# Monteverdi Optical Calibration: Spectral Response File Error in input format

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I have been trying to upload a spectral response file for optical calibration in the Monteverdi (standalone) program. I have followed the required format, but continue to get the persistent error: `ERROR: itk::ERRORERROR: itk::ERROR: SpectralSensitivityReader(0x7f8358890340): Invalid file format: SpectralSensitivityReader(0x7f835881a3b0): Invalid file format`

My input file is a simple text file for a Pleiades image with 4 bands (min, max, stepsize and then the sequential spectral response values at that stepwise), please see below. I haven't had success in finding an example input spectral response file and only have the guidelines in the software:

```
0.428 0.552 0.0025
0.007
0.069
0.093
0.115
0.125
...
0.496 0.621 0.0025
0.008
0.015
0.023
...
0.598 0.746 0.0025
0.061
0.119
0.226
...
0.752 0.948 0.0025
0.066
0.111
0.157
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of spectral sensitivity are tabulated in OTB classes now.

For Pleiades, if you've got a standard product, OTB will automatically detect the sensor and load values for spectral sensitivity in optical calibration. You should normally not have to load those values "by hand"

The SpectralSensitivityReader class is quite old, don't know . Think it was develop to parse Spot5 spectral sensitivity.

Let me know if you can make some progress.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I was having a huge issue and many errors on my OS X 10.10 installing OTB which is why I  was trying to run Monteverdi standalone. I will give it another go.